# Notice: Undefined offset while looping throw an array of objects with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I have the following array of objects:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 4
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 6
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 8
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 7
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 7
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 5
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 7
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 6
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 5
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 6
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 6
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 4
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 5
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sales] => 11
                )

        )

)
```

I want to get the total sales in each of the Objects. So I wrote this code:

```
    public function getChannelsSales ($ChannelSales) {
        $totalChannelSales = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($ChannelSales as $ChSales) {
            foreach ($ChSales as $value) {
                $totalChannelSales[$i] = $totalChannelSales [$i] + $value->Sales;
            }
            ++$i;
        }
        return $totalChannelSales;
}
```

After running the code I get the right answer:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 22
    [2] => 18
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 20
)
```

However I get also in the froint end the following messages:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ...\Sales.php on line 174
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ...\Sales.php on line 174
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in ...\Sales.php on line 174
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in ...\Sales.php on line 174
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in ...\Sales.php on line 174
```

line 174 is this one:

```
$totalChannelSales[$i] = $totalChannelSales[$i] + $value->Sales;
```

And I do not get where is the problem if even the answer is correct (as you could sum yourself)

Any Idea?

**EDIT:**

I have got a solution by adding twice the line

```
        $totalChannelSales[0] = 0;
```

- Once after creating the array and before the first foreach
- A second time between the two for each AFTER the first foreach ends

Comment: write $totalChannelSales[$i] = $value->Sales;

Comment: `$totalChannelSales[$i] = $value->Sales;`

Answer (score 1):

Array will fill your value one by one from loop. You do not need to add it.

Use below code.

```
$totalChannelSales[$i] = $value->Sales;
```

Comment: Sorry your solution gives the wrong answer:

I need to add all the sales of each of the  channels (15, 22, 18 and 20)

If I use your solution I get just the last sale of each channel (5, 7, 6, 6 and 11)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is here

```
$totalChannelSales[$i] = $totalChannelSales [$i] + $value->Sales;
```

You are trying to set index that don't even exist, you can use array_push for this, it will push elements and iterate indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I will walk you through your code to figure out error:

```
foreach ($ChannelSales as $ChSales) {
        foreach ($ChSales as $value) {
            $totalChannelSales[$i] = $totalChannelSales [$i] + $value->Sales;
        }
        ++$i;
    }
```

Now in the above code lets say at $i = 0 you are in first loop and at that time `$totalChannelSales[$i] = $totalChannelSales [$i] + $value->Sales;` will be `$totalChannelSales[0] = $totalChannelSales [0] + $value->Sales;` so it is going to fetch the $totalChannelSales [0] value which does not exist at that point same goes for other values of $i.

Answer (score 0):

```
$totalChannelSales[$i] = $totalChannelSales [$i] + $value->Sales;
```

In the above code, No value is defined for `$totalChannelSales [$i]` in the right side. You just need below assignement.

```
$totalChannelSales[$i] = $value->Sales;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

I have introduced a temp variable $tempsum which will remove all undefined issues.

```
public function getChannelsSales ($ChannelSales) {
    $totalChannelSales = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($ChannelSales as $ChSales) {
        $tempsum = 0;
        foreach ($ChSales as $value) {
            $tempsum += $value->Sales;
        }
       $totalChannelSales[$i] = $tempsum;
       $i++;
    }
   return $totalChannelSales;
}
```

Comment: I did it, but it was still giving ONE TIME the message:
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in ...\Sales.php on line 174

Comment: Would you please try $i++ in replace of ++$i, just a try.

Comment: @RafaelMunoz I have edited the code. This will resolve the issue without introducing more 0 assignment.